# Animation on Listview with Observablecollection, XamlParseException occured when sort items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm suffering from `cannot found property Background.Opacity` when I use Animation on `Listview`.

See my Gifs. following images shows my current work state.

[image]

I got an Error message that says - cannot found property `Backgorund.Opactiy`. I think It's weird, Because It works until I Sort it.

see my xaml source first.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding bsources}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DrawingBrush
                                                x:Name="errorBrush"
                                                TileMode="Tile"
                                                Viewport="0 0 1 1"
                                                ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                                <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                                                </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing>
                                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="4,2" />
                                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                            <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="4" />
                                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            </DrawingBrush>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>

                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <!-- Storyboard.TargetProperty = "opacity" throws no error -->
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                    FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                                                    Duration="0:0:1">
                                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.2" />
                                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.3" />
                                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.8" />
                                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Address}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
    <Button
        Name="Sort"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Click="Sort_Click"
        Content="Sort" />
</Grid>
```

List view has Item sources. and If item's Property `Checked` is true, then It begins `storyboard` and also makes Its background to red `drawingbrush`. the reason I think this error is weird that It works good when I click an item and make `Checked` Property is true. but when I sort `ObservableCollection` and allocate `new ObservableCollection` It throws an error. ...

in xaml Code, see my comment. at Lines, there, I tried without `Background` prefix. `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"` then It works. see follow image.

[image]

You may notify differences between first image and second image, but let me explain differences to you. first one only changes its background brush opacity, but second one change all content (including text) opacity. I want achieve first one animation without any error.

Thank you for reading.

I don't think I have a problem with csharp code - But I'll post my source code also. following source is my csharp source.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool state = false;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _bSources;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChagned([CallerMemberName] string name = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));


    public ObservableCollection<Person> bsources
    {
        get { return _bSources; }
        set { _bSources = value;  OnPropertyChagned(); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        bsources = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        { new Person("김", "부산"), new Person("정", "강원도"), new Person("최", "서울"), new Person("권", "전라도"), new Person("박", "대전") };

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Sort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (state)
        {
            bsources = new ObservableCollection<Person>(bsources.OrderBy(i => i.Checked));
            state = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            bsources = new ObservableCollection<Person>(bsources.OrderByDescending(i => i.Checked));
            state = true;
        }
    }
}
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _Checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _Checked; }
        set { _Checked = value; OnPropertyChagned(); }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChagned();  }
    }
    private string _Address;

    public string Address
    {
        get { return _Address; }
        set { _Address = value; OnPropertyChagned(); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChagned([CallerMemberName] string name=null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public Person(string name, string Address)
    {
        this.Checked = false;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Address = Address;
    }
}
```

## EDITED

**Button ADDED** for update `HasError` property that is just checking whether `checkbox` is checked or not.
following is my xaml code, little change from original xaml source. Now Binding property of `DataTrigger` is `HasError` and DataTrigger.EnterAction is Changed to `DataTrigger.ExitAction`. and below that stack panel I added new button to update `HasError` of Person class Property.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding bsources}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DrawingBrush
                                            x:Name="errorBrush"
                                            TileMode="Tile"
                                            Viewport="0 0 1 1"
                                            ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                            <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                                            </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                                <GeometryDrawing>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="4,2" />
                                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                        <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="4" />
                                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                        </DrawingBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>

                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                                                Duration="0:0:1">
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.2" />
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.3" />
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.8" />
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Address}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
<Button
    Name="UpdateAnimation"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Click="UpdateAnimation_Click"
    Content="Update Animation" />
```

```cs
//in class Mainwindow
private void UpdateAnimation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // update HasError
    foreach( Person p in bsources)
        p.HasError = p.Checked;
}

//in Person Class
/// <summary>
/// added 
/// </summary>
private bool _HasError;
public bool HasError
{
    get { return _HasError; }
    set { _HasError = value; OnPropertyChagned(); }
}
```

following gif shows an error message.

[image]

the last exception, you might ignore it. I solved with added following xaml source.

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DrawingBrush Opacity="0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

but as you see, in Gif, there is no opacity incremental changes. ... sob ..

**To short**, there is no incremental opacity changes with `DataTrigger.ExitActions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the Stackpanel not yet rendered (with it's DrawingBrush background which is animated) when you assign new instance of ObservableCollection. The DataTrigger EnterAction is triggered first, even before the StackPanel background is rendered. On this assumption, I managed to make your sorting work only by changing
DataTrigger.EnterActions  to **DataTrigger.ExitActions**. I also need to add a fallback default DrawingBrush in case you remove the check. Below the updated style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DrawingBrush />
                <!--A default drawing brush-->
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DrawingBrush x:Name="errorBrush"
                                  TileMode="Tile"
                                  Viewport="0 0 1 1"
                                  ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                        <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                        </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0"
                                                  EndPoint="4,2" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="Red"
                                         Thickness="4" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    </DrawingBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!-- Storyboard.TargetProperty = "opacity" throws no error -->
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                                                       Duration="0:0:1">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                  Value="0.2" />
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                                                  Value="0.3" />
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="0.8" />
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                                  Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
This is how I managed to get your updated question with HasError to work. Please give this a try:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding bsources}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DrawingBrush x:Key="DB" Opacity="0" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0 0 1 1" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                    </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="4,2" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="4" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Style.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DB}"/>
                        </Style.Setters>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                                                Duration="0:0:1">
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.2" />
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.3" />
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.8" />
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DrawingBrush Opacity="0" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Address}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: HI Insane, Thank you for your solution. you suggested nice approach. It works good with source that is posted, but I'm worried your solution is not enough to solve my original problem. actually my exact source code is quite different. I'm really sorry about that... I didn't expect my posted source is different with my original source code. I'll edit my post to simulate same problem. sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I solved with adding another `DataTrigger` Element which Value attribute False. but with your solution I entirely lost my opacity changes animation

Comment: @JeongYoHan Please see if the updated answer helps.

Comment: Sorry but your source does not work. with DrawingBrush Opacity =0, It does not show any animation. but With opacity =1 , I can see animation works. but there is no incremental opacity changes in animation.

Comment: Did you replace your whole ListView code with the updated answer? It seems to be animating fine when I run it. Anyways, what it seems is that there is an issue where your DrawingBrush is not yet rendered. So a good approach will be to always have one as the StackPanel background with default transparent background from load.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I did exactly replace my source with your source. but I didn't... Lol... thank you so much!